# How to move the first instance of a string in a column so it's before that string's group while accounting for multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with multiple columns like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Level = c(
    'Midwest',
    'Wisconsin: Good',
    'Wisconsin: Neutral',
    'Wisconsin: Bad',
    NA,
    'Minnesota: Good',
    'Minnesota: Neutral',
    'Minnesota: Bad',
    NA,
    'New England',
    'New Hampshire: Good',
    'New Hampshire: Neutral',
    'New Hampshire: Bad',
    NA,
    'Vermont: Good',
    'Vermont: Neutral',
    'Vermont: Bad'
  ),
  TotalPct = c(
    NA,
    '75%',
    '71%',
    '65%',
    NA,
    '82%',
    '76%',
    '53%',
    NA,
    NA,
    '68%',
    '98%',
    '45%',
    NA,
    '79%',
    '93%',
    '48%'
  )
)
```

I'm interested in doing two things to this dataframe:

1. Grab the first instance of the `Good` level for each state and place
   it in a new row about the `Good` level, and...
2. Remove the state names from each level so it just shows `Good`, `Neutral`, and `Bad` below each state name.

The result would look like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(
  Level = c(
    'Midwest',
    'Wisconsin',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad',
    NA,
    'Minnesota',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad',
    NA,
    'New England',
    'New Hampshire',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad',
    NA,
    'Vermont',
    'Good',
    'Neutral',
    'Bad'
  ),
  TotalPct = c(
    NA,
    NA,
    '75%',
    '71%',
    '65%',
    NA,
    NA,
    '82%',
    '76%',
    '53%',
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    '68%',
    '98%',
    '45%',
    NA,
    NA,
    '79%',
    '93%',
    '48%'
  )
)
```

What's the best way to go about achieving this using R, ideally using `dplyr` if possible?

Comment: Are you sure that objective 1. is being fulfilled by your `df_desired`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(Level,sep=": ") %>% 
  filter(
    (Level %in% c("Good", "Neutral", "Bad") | is.na(TotalPct)
     | lead(Level) == "Good")) %>% 
  mutate(TotalPct=ifelse(!(Level %in% c("Good", "Neutral", "Bad")), NA, TotalPct))

#> # A tibble: 21 × 2
#>    Level     TotalPct
#>    <chr>     <chr>   
#>  1 Midwest   <NA>    
#>  2 Wisconsin <NA>    
#>  3 Good      75%     
#>  4 Neutral   71%     
#>  5 Bad       65%     
#>  6 <NA>      <NA>    
#>  7 Minnesota <NA>    
#>  8 Good      82%     
#>  9 Neutral   76%     
#> 10 Bad       53%     
#> # … with 11 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear as to what you want, but this is usually very useful format:

```r
df %>%
  separate(Level, c("State", "Level"), sep = ": ") %>%
  na.omit() %>% 
  print(n = Inf)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   State         Level   TotalPct
   <chr>         <chr>   <chr>   
 1 Wisconsin     Good    75%     
 2 Wisconsin     Neutral 71%     
 3 Wisconsin     Bad     65%     
 4 Minnesota     Good    82%     
 5 Minnesota     Neutral 76%     
 6 Minnesota     Bad     53%     
 7 New Hampshire Good    68%     
 8 New Hampshire Neutral 98%     
 9 New Hampshire Bad     45%     
10 Vermont       Good    79%     
11 Vermont       Neutral 93%     
12 Vermont       Bad     48%
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep this one in the format I have it in with the blank rows, so `na.omit` won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

This feels clunky but I think it gets there:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  separate(Level, c("region", "rating"), sep = ": ") %>%
  mutate(copies = if_else(rating != "Good" | is.na(rating), 1, 2)) %>%
  uncount(copies, .id = "id") %>%
  mutate(TotalPct = if_else(rating == "Good" & id == 1, NA_character_, TotalPct),
         level = if_else(is.na(TotalPct), region, rating)) %>%
  select(level, TotalPct)
```

Result

```
           level TotalPct
1        Midwest     <NA>
2      Wisconsin     <NA>
3           Good      75%
4        Neutral      71%
5            Bad      65%
6           <NA>     <NA>
7      Minnesota     <NA>
8           Good      82%
9        Neutral      76%
10           Bad      53%
11          <NA>     <NA>
12   New England     <NA>
13 New Hampshire     <NA>
14          Good      68%
15       Neutral      98%
16           Bad      45%
17          <NA>     <NA>
18       Vermont     <NA>
19          Good      79%
20       Neutral      93%
21           Bad      48%
```